# How to chose 4 elements from a list which when multiplied give the maximum product, when the list also contains negative values?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

`lis = [-1,-2,3,-4,-5,7,8,9]`

The output should be the following:
`1512 (= 9 * 8 * 7 * 3)`

Ex2:
`lis=[7,1,-1,-2,3,-8]`

Should output: `336 (= -8 * -2 * 7 * 3)`

The output should be the combination of those 4 elements which produce the maximum product even when the list contains negative integers.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: geeksforgeeks.org/python-maximum-product-using-k-elements/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np                                 
from itertools import permutations                 
                                               
lis = [-1, -2, 3, -4, -5, 7, 8, 9]                 
lis2 = [7, 1, -1, -2, 3, -8]                       
                                               
                                               
def get_max(input_list):                           
    v = []                                         
    input_list = permutations(input_list, 4)       
    for val_lis in input_list:                     
        v.append(np.prod(val_lis))                 
    return max(v)                                  
                                               
                                               
print(get_max(lis2))
```

Prints:

for lis -> 1512

for lis2 -> 336

Note that there are more efficient ways to achieve your goal than writing all the results of combining the lists and getting the maximum out of them as I have done.